# Browser spellcheck on static text in contenteditable SPAN

Tags: jquery, contenteditable, spell-checking

I have some text elements on a page and want to draw user's attention to any spelling mistakes; I've been doing this by forcing spellcheck which then displays wiggly-red-underline.

This seems to have stopped working (in Chrome) recently, is there a way to achieve this please?

I've been doing this:

```
<span contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true" class="spellcheck">Some Text</span>
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".spellcheck").each(function(){this.focus()});
    $("#SomeIDNearTopOfPage").focus();
});
```

which used to work OK

(It seems to me that there used to be a visual effect of the page scrolling, as each SPAN was "visited", but I don't seem to see that happening now - or, maybe, the number of suitable SPANs on the page is small, compared with previously, and is happening faster than I can see - just mentioning this in case relevant)

If I manually click on the SPAN and append e.g. a space then the wiggly-red-line appears.